# Web Development - Security

Tags: javascript, html, security

In terms of security, is it generally a better practice to keep all of your javascript files embedded in the source html, or is it more secure to link to an external html file from the source html. Are they treated the exact same and I'm just being an idiot?

I am very new to web development and I don't really understand the encryption side of things:

(1) Embedded javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>

    <body>

        ...

        <script>
            function myFunction()
            {
                // is this secure?
            }
        </script>

        ...

    </body>
</html>
```

(2) External javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        ...
        <script src="myFunction.js"></script> // or is this better?
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: they are the exact same. nothing delivered to the client is secure.

Comment: Using external javascript is not a security feature. Instead of sending to the client an html file containing your js script, you will send the html and the js file(s) it refers to. Using external JS is only a best practice as you may reuse the same functions in different html pages of your website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that makes it to the client side can be captured and viewed. So all JS files are open to viewed along with your HTML.
For security, if you have business logic or sensitive code that needs to remain unseen you need to place that on the server side and only access the results of that code running via API calls.